# image resizing in PHP

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd, image-resizing

While i was doing some image processing, i found out that GD and Imagick in PHP does not resize image to color pixel identical level, which in most cases, were not needed.
Now in case, i need a image from whatever dimension to scale to 256*256

To make sure the TEST  results are consistent, i used a 256*256 image and resize it to it's own size.

what i've attempted:

```
imagecopyresized($new, $img, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h); //256 , 256
```

and

```
$compression_type = imagick::COMPRESSION_NO;
$images_ima = new Imagick($image_path);    //$image_path = path to image...
$images_ima->setImageCompression($compression_type); 
$images_ima->setImageCompressionQuality(100); 
$images_ima->sampleImage($X_SIZE,$Y_SIZE); // 256 ,256
$images_ima->writeImages($dest_path, true); //destination path
```

none of them worked, if i compare the output with the original image, it will look something like this:
[image: Araxis merge comparison on original VS resized]

it looks like the functions i've used are resampling the image since the variations in the RGB value between both image are small

i can achieve pixel to pixel identical resizing from 256*256 to 256*256 in photoshop, OSX preview, and even Pixelformer. 
i was wondering how can that be done i PHP?

Comment: Why don't you just use imagecopy if you detect the pixel dimensions are identical?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question but each image processing library will normally *not* use the same exact algorithm. Whatever your tests are, they can't rely on such assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your image format (jpeg - assumed from 100 quality setting) is a lossy format you won't get a lossless throughput this way as you're recompressing the image.

You should try to detect image dimensions and use the original image if the dimensions are already correct.

When you don't change the dimensions (original dimensions = dimensions after resizing) in Photoshop or OSX preview they won't recompress the image, that's why you won't see any change.

Comment: but in my code, there is a line where i set the compression value to 100 which is no compression. isn't that a image uncompressed will remain the same? even if i am using JPEG, when loss of quality would happen; why did the pixel's value changes not even before i compress it? For example => imagecolorat($img).... the values retrieved are not identical to the original one.

Comment: jpeg with a quality of 100 is far away from uncompressed

Comment: if you get different color values right after decompression you might want to check for the presence of color profiles in the image as imagemagick/gd might ignore them in difference to some image edit programs...

Comment: ohh.. i didn't thought about that, right , i'll give it a shot by checking the colour profile

Comment: tried, no, here's why => 1) read image to $img 2) imagecolorat($img) (there is no change comparing with the original image in THIS STEP) 3)imagecopyresized($img) 4) imagecolorat($img) again, the values are NOW modified...

Comment: anyway, you point me in the right direction, there are multiple places in my code where there is no defined colour profile as still reads image, i'll create my own function to resize images and set colour profiles. but still, if you have anything to add, please do so :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's due to recompressing, you might want to try it using png or bmp images as those are lossless formats. If they don't change then it's most probably an issue with recompressing the image. On the other hand, this wouldn't be the first bug i encounter in imagemagick, maybe you want to add this to their bugtracker just in case :)